# Euclidean Geometry- Orthocenter Reflection

Tags: geometry

[image]

My thoughts here are to show that the 3 reflected points are all equidistant from the circumcenter and hence they uniquely determine a circle (the circumscribed circle). However, I'm not sure how to find a relation between the orthocenter and the midpoints of the sides.

Comment: Could you tell me where you got this question?

Comment: The same question (Lemma 1.17) is also in EGMO, Evan Chen

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $D$ is the reflected of orthocenter $H$ around the midpoint of $BC$. Then it is not difficult to prove that $BDCH$ is a parallelogram and $\angle BDC = \angle BHC = \pi - \angle BAC$, which is a sufficient condition for $ABCD$ to lie on a circle.